# How can I handle 204 status with Typescript and fetch?

Tags: javascript, typescript, fetch

I'm trying to create post request using fetch and typescript.
But can't create 204 status handler.

I have already tried to return promise with null value but it does't work.

```js
    postRequest = async <T>(url: string, body: any): Promise<T> => {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
        });

        // here is my problem
        if (response.status === 204) {
            // error is: "Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'T'."
            return null;
            // I have tried to return promise, but it doesn't work.
            // error is: "Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to 
            // parameter of type 'T | PromiseLike<T> | undefined'."
            return new Promise(resolve => resolve(null));
        }

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(response.statusText);
        }

        return await response.json() as Promise<T>;
    };


    postRequest<{data: boolean}>('request', { someValue: 1234 });
```

Comment: Two things, first you can wrap a value in a promise trivially by using the static method like so: `Promise.resolve(null);` so no need to call constructor. And undefined is a valid value per the error message, so unless you really need null you can always `return Promise.resolve(undefined)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) to signal that either a `Promise<T>` or a `Promise<null>` gets returned:

```
postRequest = async <T>(url: string, body: any): Promise<T | null> => {
```

In this example, the return type is `Promise<T | null>`, which indicates that either `T` or `null` will be used for a resolved promise.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your function to return possibly `null` you have to add it to the return type.

```
postRequest = async <T>(url: string, body: any): Promise<T|null> => {
...
}
```

And you don't need await the return value in an async function, the created promise already handles the awaiting for you:

```
return response.json() as T;
```